# Zero Frequency and Small Sample Size

Tags: confidence-interval, small-sample, frequency

I have a situation where the skeletons from one of three archaeological sites do not display a bone condition called periostitis that is found at the other two.

The relevant statistics are:

```
Site 1: freq=.167, n=48 
Site 2: freq=.000, n=5  
Site 3: freq=.250, n=36.
```

Since it is unlikely that individuals from Site 2 would not have periostitis (for anthropological reasons), it seems reasonable that the small sample size (n=5) is to blame for the freq=0.

As a means of testing independence between the sites and frequency of periostitis, I performed a Fisher-Freeman-Halton test, which yielded p=.495; but, in accordance with the ASA statement on p-values, I'm trying to get away from null hypothesis significance testing (NHST) as the only support for my findings.

With other skeletal traits, I've showed that the overlap between the 95% CIs for various frequencies support the findings of the NHST, but the freq=0 reduces the value of this approach in this case. However, if I assume that Site 2 has a freq=.200 (which is the average frequency for all three sites), there is considerable overlap between the 95% CIs for the three sites, thereby supporting the NHST result.

This approach is reasonable since the 3 sites are close to each other geographically, and periostitis is a very common condition in prehistoric populations. Also, the binomial distribution shows a prob=.328 that samples of 5 would have no periostitis if the actual frequency is 1 in 5 (freq=.200).

Is this a legitimate analysis? Is projecting a frequency, based on logic but not supported by data, acceptable? Please give me your opinions.

Answer (score 2):

I will only try to address the specific question about getting a confidence interval for site 2 where the estimated proportion is 0. A nice method to construct a confidence interval with good coverage properties in low-sample cases (like for site 2) is that proposed by [Agresti and Coull (1998)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2685469?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents). [Agresti and Caffo (2000) summarize that method here.](http://users.stat.ufl.edu/~aa/articles/agresti_caffo_2000.pdf)

You can effectively add two pseudo observations to the successes and failures. I think this has some intuition similar to what you stated -- you are sort of doing a weighted average of the result you get (0) and 1/2, with the weighting dictated by the sample size.

Formally, following Agresti and Caffo (2000), the confidence interval would be given by:
$$\tilde{p} \pm z_{0.025} \sqrt{\tilde{p}(1-\tilde{p})/\tilde{n}},$$
where $\tilde{n} = n + 4$ (and $n = 5$ for site 2), and $\tilde{p} = (X + 2) / (n + 4)$, where $X$ is the number of successes (0 for site 2).

Doing this you would get a confidence interval of $(0, 0.49)$ (I put a lower-limit at 0 for obvious reasons).

See [this link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/263664/agresti-coull-interval-question) for more detailed discussion.

Answering the more general question about what to do here -- producing a confidence interval for site 2 in the way I suggested is what I would do. There are probably some Bayesian approaches: suppose you observe site 1 and site 3, and these inform your prior expectation of the underlying proportion at site 2. But I think you have reason to expect your sites to have different underlying proportions (and actually this is a thing you are trying to assess), so I wouldn't actually go this route.

Comment: Thank you for the input, bzki...I appreciate the suggestion, and will give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

The analysis of @bzki (+1) seems reasonable.

A brief Bayesian
analysis might begin by noticing that you have seen 16 skeletons
with periostitis out of 84 skeletons at nearby sites. So a reasonable
posterior distribution of the rate $\lambda$ might be
$\mathsf{Gamma}(\text{shape}=16,\, \text{rate}=84),$ which has
mean $0.190$ and puts 95% of its probability in $(0.109, 0.295).$

In R:

```
qgamma(c(.025,.975), 16, 84)
[1] 0.1088736 0.2945264
```

[image]

So you should not be surprised to see no instances of periostitis
at a site with only five skeletons.

Comment: Thanx, BruceET...I appreciate the extra support for the belief that freq=0 is due to the small sample size and probably does not reflect the actual frequency of periostitis.